# Beamer: Is it possible to draw an arrow from frame body to a diagram?

Tags: beamer, arrows, tikz-arrows, overlays

I wonder if it is possible to overlay/draw an arrow from the frame body to a diagram (or even somewhere within the diagram) as in the figures below.

(The arrows don't have to bend like that)

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\title[Title]{Presentation}
\author{Sandro Botticelli}
\institute{Italy}
\date{1484}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Wow, what a beautiful girl

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{Venus}
    \caption{Nascita di Venere}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: *Wow, what a beautiful question*. `:)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I'd recommend using Ti*k*Z along with the libraries `tikzmark` and `overlay-beamer-styles` for that. (The file `Venus` has on my machine a slightly different content. **UPDATE**: Now with a [truly beautiful girl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGVai.png), super big thanks to @samcarter ;-) If you need to determine the position of the arrow more precisely, there are advanced options which I will be happy to add if needed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% \usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,overlay-beamer-styles,babel} % babel just in case you
% reinstall the babel package 

\title[Title]{Presentation}
\author{Sandro Botticelli}
\institute{Italy}
\date{1484}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Wow, what a beautiful \tikzmarknode{girl}{girl}

\begin{figure}
\tikzmarknode{Venus}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{Venus.png}}
    \caption{Nascita di Venere}
\end{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[-latex,visible on=<1>] (girl.east) to[out=0,in=45] ([xshift=0.1cm,yshift=-1cm]Venus.north east);
\draw[-latex,visible on=<2>] (girl.east) to[out=0,in=45] ([xshift=-2.4cm,yshift=-2cm]Venus.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ceci n'est pas une fille!

Comment: +1 for the Venus

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGVai.png

Comment: @marmot You're welcome :)

Comment: @gusbrs Et maintenant?

Comment: @samcarter hahaha! C'est ne pas encore une fille. Jolie, mais, c'est une "marmotte"!  :-)

Comment: @samcarter Btw, if I heard correctly, congrats on tikzlings!