# How to draw arrows from floating text into a picture in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, tikz-arrows, text

I currently have the following figure and code

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \node (image) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{tj}};
            \node[align=center, yshift = 1.5cm, xshift = 4cm] at (current page.center) {Tom};
            \node[align=center, yshift = -1.5cm, xshift = 4cm] at (current page.center) {Jerry};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I want to draw two arrows from Tom and Jerry to the location of their respective faces. I know there is a way to accomplish this using Tikz node. But I am not sure how to do this without compilation errors.

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjgd2.png)

Can someone help me achieve this effect?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457969/beamer-is-it-possible-to-draw-an-arrow-from-frame-body-to-a-diagram or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186389/how-can-i-annotate-an-image-with-arrow-and-text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799), it is convenient to introduce a local coordinate system on top of the image.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\only<1>{Draw a coordinate system on top of the image}%
\only<2>{Draw the text nodes (with some generous inner sep)}%
\only<3>{Connec the text nodes to the points}%
\only<4>{Remove the grid}%
}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (image) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{tj}};
            \begin{scope}[shift={(image.south west)},x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
            \only<1-3>{
             \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
             \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
             \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }            
             }
             \only<2->{
             \node[fill=white,font=\large,inner sep=4pt] (Tom) at (0.9,0.74) {Tom};
             \node[fill=white,font=\large,inner sep=4pt] (Jerry) at (0.9,0.23) {Jerry};
             }
             \only<3->{
             \draw[ultra thick,red] (Tom) -- (0.49,0.42);
             \draw[ultra thick,red] (Jerry) -- (0.66,0.23);
             }
            \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, in the end you may want to erase the grid.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799
\begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (image) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{tj}};
            \begin{scope}[shift={(image.south west)},x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
             \node[fill=white,font=\large,inner sep=4pt,align=center] 
                (Tom) at (0.9,0.74) {Bad\\ Tom};
             \node[fill=white,font=\large,inner sep=4pt,align=center] (Jerry) at (0.9,0.23) 
                {Tasty\\ Jerry};
             \draw[ultra thick,red,-stealth] (Tom) -- (0.49,0.42);
             \draw[ultra thick,red,-stealth] (Jerry) -- (0.66,0.23);
            \end{scope}     
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you were using `remember picture,overlay` without actually using it. As long as you do not really make use of it I recommend dropping it. I also added the arrow heads and multiline nodes, as asked in the comments.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to easily put an arrow at the end <-

Comment: @ShamisenExpert Sure, just replace `\draw[ultra thick,red] (Tom) -- (0.49,0.42);
             \draw[ultra thick,red] (Jerry) -- (0.66,0.23);` by `\draw[ultra thick,red,-stealth] (Tom) -- (0.49,0.42);
             \draw[ultra thick,red,-stealth] (Jerry) -- (0.66,0.23);`. (Will decouple now for a while.)

Comment: Ok. I wonder if there is a way to write {Bad \\ Tom} i.e., Tom beneath Bad. I tried to do this but received errors.

Comment: @ShamisenExpert You can definitely have mutliline text in nodes, you only need to specify the alignment. I added examples with `align=center` to the answer.